# google api with java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have been working on this for a few days now, and it still gives me headaches! I want to access a google sheet from my google drive, and i have succeeded using this authentication method.

```
public void authenticate() throws MalformedURLException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException, ServiceException, URISyntaxException {

        SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");    
        File p12 = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("p12File.p12").getPath());

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"};
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(ClientId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)                   
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                .build();

        service = new SpreadsheetService("test");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
}
```

The thing is that this only works for my own account, since i signed up with google and used their [console developer page](https://console.developers.google.com/).
Now i would like to make it more generic, so I shouldnt hardcode my credential on the application. 
The problem is that this is going to be a shell application, with no gui and most likely i would make it an automated procedure, so i just cant open up a web-browser and ask the user to sign in.
Is there a way to pass the users username and password and the authentication procedure returns a list of the google sheets under that user? I have been looking for something like this on the google API web pages, but I am completely lost.

Thanks

Comment: Is there no way to prompt the user to enter their information and then have it become autonomous after that?

Comment: I guess i could ask username/password as arguments prior to execution. lets say yes, this might be possible

Comment: Well if possible, just allow the user to enter the credentials, and pass those arguments as the username/password in the part of the process where it is self sufficient.

Comment: @user2277872 the problem is that i set up the application for using my account, and accessing a google sheet that is shared with the `client ID` user. This was the only way i managed to do it. So i cant use that. I need some other method, that i just dont know